# Your configured rpc port: 8899 is already in use

Tags: anchor, testing

When I run `anchor test` command get this error .

`Error: Your configured rpc port: 8899 is already in use`

I checked that port but look like there is no such process is using that port on my device .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anchor Test start's a local validator deploys the program and then run's the test functions. If you want to just run the test's use the command `anchor run test`.If you wish to use `anchor test` then you have to kill the local validator that is already in use.

Comment: How can I kill the local validator that is already in use ?