# Error: Your configured rpc port: 8899 is already in use

Tags: testing, anchor-test, solana-test-validator, solana-cli

I am getting this error when i am running the command `anchor test` :
`Error: Your configured rpc port: 8899 is already in use`

And i know i have to kill the local validator from [this](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1241/your-configured-rpc-port-8899-is-already-in-use) question but i don't know how to kill the local validator .

Answer (score 3):

If you're running `anchor test` and you have a local validator already running, you can use the following command to skip the validator startup:

`anchor test --skip-local-validator`

Otherwise you can kill whatever is running on port 8899 with:

```
$ lsof -i :8899
<PID>

$ kill -9 <PID>
```